# How can I remove all occurences of two values in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to remove all occurences of two values in a list using one line. I have tried the `filter` + `lambda` method and list comprehension, but it's not working the way I would expect.

Something like:

```
s2 = [0, 0, 3, 11, 14, 17, 18, 18]
# I want to remove all 0 and 18 from s2 list
# i.e. I want output: s2_filter = [3, 11, 14, 17]

s2_filter = filter (lambda a: a != 0 or 18, s2)
>>> s2 = [0, 0, 3, 11, 14, 17, 18, 18] # not what I'm expecting

s2_filter = [i for i in s2 if i != 0 or 18]
>>> s2 = [0, 0, 3, 11, 14, 17, 18, 18] # not what I'm expecting
```

I guess there is something wrong with the `or` but I cannot figure out how I should write this correctly.

Can you help?

Comment: Bad example, I'll edit it. Sometimes they occur just once, sometimes more than once.

Comment: No, `i != 0 and i != 18` with an `and`...

Comment: or `i not in (0, 18)`

Comment: Why are you looking for a solution to this private case? Why not looking for a generic solution that handles any set of number instead?

Comment: FWIW, `0 or 18` evaluates to `18`. Check it out in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just filter over if i is not in a non desirable list:

```
s2 = [0, 0, 3, 11, 14, 17, 18, 18]
s2_filter = [i for i in s2 if i not in [0, 18]]
s2_filter
[3, 11, 14, 17]
```